# Nvidia 5400M DVI Output Lost Color and Changed to Grayscale

Tags: lenovo-laptop, docking-station

I have a Lenovo T530 with an Nvidia 5400M GPU, It is docked into a Lenovo docking station with 2 DVI monitors plugged in. Today I unplugged one of the DVI cables while both monitors were turned on and plugged it back in, this resulted in both DVI outputs changing from color to grayscale (black and white) output...

I have tried: rebooting, redocking the laptop multiple times, changing the windows display settings(resolution, color, etc) nothing will turn the color back on.

If I undock and use the built-in laptop display the color is fine.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Sounds line hardware damage have you replaced the dock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer on Lenovo support forums, apparently this bug can be triggered by a number of different causes, unplugging dvi cables, attached projectors, etc..

To fix:

1. open nvidia control panel
2. Goto "Adjust desktop color settings" pane
3. Change to "use nvidia settings"
4. Drag the "Digital Vibrance" slider from 0 to 50

Comment: Had this exact issue with a Dell E6420 / Nvidia 5200M

Comment: Same issue with Dell Precision M4700 /NVidia Quadro K2000M (external monitor conencted via HDMI)